# How to open a specific C++ file in CodeBlocks using Java program?

Tags: java

I have created a Java program to create a C++ file taking the file name as the user input and then after the file creation is done, the program should automatically open the created C++ file in CodeBlocks.

```
 System.out.println("Enter the Name of the file to be created ---");
         name =sc.next();
         File f = new File(name+".cpp");
         if(f.exists())
         {
             System.out.println("File already exists");
         }
         else
         {

             try{ 
                 f.createNewFile();
                 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name+".cpp");
                 fw.write("#include<bits/stdc++.h>\r\nusing namespace std;\r\nint main()\r\n{\r\n"
                 + "ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);\r\ncin.tie(NULL);\r\n\r\nreturn 0;\r\n}");
                 fw.close();
                }
             catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);} 
             System.out.println("!! File Sucessfully Created !!");
             try {
                  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                  r.exec("CodeBlocks C:\\Users\\ADITYA\\Documents\\codeblocks progs\\"+name+".cpp");
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());                
                 }

         }
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Please ask the question properly. Tell us what isn't working, or put the StackTrace in, or tell us what you want the point of this question to be.

Comment: (OT: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: @YogeshSudheerModak  the .cpp file is created but i expect the program to open that newly created file in codeblocks automatically , which is not happening , what should i do ?.....after creation of that file i get the output message "Something went wrong " i.e. the message in the catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path/to/codeblock/executable --file="+filePath);
```

[command line arguments](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_command_line_arguments)